# Sending .Net Core application settings to kubernetes pods as environment variables

Tags: azure, kubernetes, .net-core

I'm hosting some stuff as an AppService in Azure and use environment variables to differentiate settings for different slots (test, dev etc).

If the AppSettings.json file contains a structure like:

```
{
   "ConnectionString": {
      "MyDb": "SomeConnectionString"
   }
}
```

I can set the environment variable "ConnectionString:MyDb" to "SomeConnectionString" and .Net Core will understand that the `:` means child level.

But in Kubernetes I cannot use `:` as part of the environment key. Is there another way to handle hierarchy or do I need to switch to flat settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are referring to the `env` in the container definition for a Pod. From the YAML/JSON perspective, I don't see a problem with specifying a `:` in a key for an environment variable. You can also put it within quotes and should be valid JSON/YAML:

```
# convert.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: envar-demo
  labels:
    purpose: demonstrate-envars
spec:
  containers:
  - name: envar-demo-container
    image: dotnetapp
    env:
    - name: ConnectionString:Mydb
      value: ConnectionString
```

Same in JSON:

```
$ kubectl convert -f convert.yaml -o=json
{
    "kind": "Pod",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "envar-demo",
        "creationTimestamp": null,
        "labels": {
            "purpose": "demonstrate-envars"
        }
    },
    "spec": {
        "containers": [
            {
                "name": "envar-demo-container",
                "image": "dotnetapp",
                "env": [
                    {
                        "name": "ConnectionString:Mydb",
                        "value": "ConnectionString"
                    }
                ],
                "resources": {},
                "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
                "terminationMessagePolicy": "File",
                "imagePullPolicy": "Always"
            }
        ],
        "restartPolicy": "Always",
        "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 30,
        "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
        "securityContext": {},
        "schedulerName": "default-scheduler"
    },
    "status": {}
}
```

However, looks like this was a known issue with Windows/.NET applications. An attempt to fix it [has been tried](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/59599) and ditched due to the fact the this is not valid in Bash. But looks like they settled to use the `__` instead of `:` [workaround](https://github.com/kubernetes/website/pull/7657/files)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, example

In the Appsettings.json

```
 "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Azure": "Server=tcp:uw2qdisa
```

In the manifest.yml

```
    env:
    - name:  ConnectionStrings__Azure
      valueFrom:
        configMapKeyRef:
          name: config-disa
          key: ConnectionStrings
```

**Explanation on Kubernetes**

- Some .Net Core applications expect environment variables with a colon (`:`) in the name.  Kubernetes currently does not allow this.  Replace colon (`:`) with  double underscore (`__`) as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?tabs=basicconfiguration#configuration-by-environment).